# Multiple MediaEngines SetSource blocks rendering

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I'm using multiple MediaEngines to display multiple videos at the same time. When one video is playing and I change the source on another one it makes the other video stop rendering for about 1 sec.

It seems that MediaEngine its reusing IO threads and its making other videos stall.

Is there a way to load the source in a different threads?

Comment: Does it work differently if you use IMFMediaEngineEx::SetSourceFromByteStream 
 instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfmediaengine/nf-mfmediaengine-imfmediaengineex-setsourcefrombytestream

Comment: Works the same. It seems to happen only when loading big files (4k video)

Comment: then you may need to use a different method, such as IMFSourceReader and render to DX 11 directly

Comment: Do you have the same problem, when using two video players ?